# React useEffect re-renders for same dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

My app has 2 navtabs, one is `Projects` and the other one is `Project ideas`. The ideas from the second tab, are present in the first tab as a non-editable fields. I fetch these projects using a saga and I keep the data in a Redux state. The fetch is based only on the `projectId`.

My goal here is NOT to fetch if the `projectId` kept being the same or I just switched from `Project ideas` to `Projects` because I have the same data in both places. In order to do that, I wrote this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getProjects(projectId));
}, [projectId, dispatch]);
```

So I use `useEffect()` for this and then I get the data through a `useSelector()`. However, if I switch from `Projects` to `Project ideas`, this `useEffect()` executes even though the `projectId` stays the same.

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve fetching only if the `projectId` changes?

Comment: HI anthino12, Can you please mention from where you get projectId. I assume that if the ProjectId coming from the redux store then it must be props.projectId. isn't it?

Comment: The projectId is a param I get through my URL. That is the currently opened Project.

Comment: useEffect executes on every re-render if you don't provide any dependency. So, as much I understand the problem, what you can try is --

useEffect(() => {
if(projectId){
  dispatch(getProjects(projectId));
}
}, []);